# Bringing one cell phone from US to India for personal use, is this allowed?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, cellphones

I'm bringing only one cell phone from US to India for personal use, is this allowed ?

Comment: Obviously people travel to India with a personal use cellphone every day. Are you asking about specifically a new cellphone bought outside India?

Comment: Are you asking about Indian "personal use" non-dutiable (duty-free) import-allowances for electronics?

Answer (score 0):

If this source is correct, it depends on the financial value, not the quantity.

According to [immihelp](http://www.immihelp.com/travel-to-india/baggage-allowance-rules/indian-residents.html)

```
                                         Age 10 & over   Age below 10
if stay abroad for more then 3 days      Rs. 45,000      Rs. 17,500
if stay abroad up to 3 days              Rs. 17,500      Rs.  3,000
```

The customs staff have a database of values, they might ignore any invoice you show.